# SqlDataAdapter: Empty result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I wrote this little function to do queries on a SQL Server 2005 database:

```
public DataSet Query(string query, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    DataSet result = new DataSet();

    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in parameters)
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(pair.Key, SqlDbType.Text).Value = pair.Value;
        }
        adapter.Fill(result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I call it like this:

```
Query("SELECT * FROM Database.Tab.le WHERE somecol LIKE '%1%'", new Dictionary<string, string>() {  });
```

I get a lot of results. But what I want is to call it like this:

```
Query("SELECT * FROM Database.Tab.le WHERE somecol LIKE '@number'", new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"@number", "%1%"}  });
```

This, however, returns zero rows. I would like to know why and how to fix it.

Comment: Change `{"number", "%1%"}` to `{"@number", "%1%"}` - you forgot the @ symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try below

```
Query("SELECT * FROM Database.Tab.le WHERE somecol LIKE @number", new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"@number", "%1%"}  });
```

(changed '@number' in sql as `@number` and gave parameter as `@number`)

Comment: @jgillich please note, there is big different between `LIKE '@number'` and `LIKE @number`

Answer (score 1):

OK you need to change your code to use SqlParameter objects. For example:

```
public DataSet Query(string query, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    DataSet result = new DataSet();

    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in parameters)
        {
            //THIS BIT IS IMPORTANT, NOTE THE STRING FORMAT!
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(string.Format("@{0}", pair.Key), pair.Value));
        }
        adapter.Fill(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing `parameter` to this query, it may be possible that number which you are passing to it is `not exists` in database.

And in direct query with `%1%` it will sure give you all the numbers in DB starting or having `preceded or followed` with 1. (If such records do exists)

Or Try following

```
Query("SELECT * FROM Database.Tab.le WHERE somecol LIKE @number", new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"@number", "%1%"}  });
```

Comment: OP indicated that he was getting results when the value was hard-coded in the query; it was only when tried with the parameter that 0 results were returned - because the value for the parameter was not being picked up.